# How to understand this Lagrangian function?

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier

I am reading this question: [shortest distance from point to hyperplane lagrange method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588421/shortest-distance-from-point-to-hyperplane-lagrange-method)

And in the answer, it directly says "Consider the Lagrangian function" $$L(\mathbf x,\lambda)=\|\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0\|^2+2\lambda(\mathbf w^T\mathbf x+b)$$

My question is:  $$\|\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0\|^2$$

Why is this term squared without squared root? and how to understand the whole Lagrangian function? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is simply the definition of the Lagrangian function.  The relevant proofs work out when the Lagrangian is defined like this.

Comment: In this case, minimizing something is the same as minimizing its square. The square makes things much simpler.

Comment: @NicNic8 thank you for your reply but I'm still confused. In this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450370/lagrange-multipliers-to-find-shortest-distance The first term of the Lagrangian function is not squared, so why it is squared here?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your reply. But the derivative will become different if you square the first term of the Lagrangian function...

Comment: It does not change anything to the problem. Think about minimizing a distance under any constraint. For sure, the derivative will be different but the )problem is really simpler. Why are using least-square methods ? Just for that.